# Update template of component from typescript with Angular2

Tags: html, angular

I have a Div where I add dynamically HTML code and I take this code HTML to save it in database (database with spring).

Then I get code HTML saved inside database the problem is that some  operations that I used to update dynamically my div for example I have inline CKEditor for some Divs or insert other Divs not work when I get code code from database.

So I ask if they are any way to update a template of component from typescript because I just using like this:

```
$('#content').html(this.section.content);
```

with jquery

Answer (score 1):

This is the angular2 way to perform **html binding**:

```
<div id="content" [innerHTML]="this.section.content">
</div>
```